# Linear Regression with Learned Feature Selection?

Tags: regression, linear-model, feature-selection

I have a question related to linear regression that stems from my research. Suppose I have two real matrices:

1. Design matrix $X \in \mathbb{R}^{N \times D}$
2. Target matrix $Y \in \mathbb{R}^{N \times E}$

For concreteness, this data might arise from students taking an exam with many questions. We have $N$ students with $D$ covariates (age, family income, parental education, etc.) and the exam has $E$ questions.

What people in my field do is first take an average over the $E$ columns of $Y$:

$$ \bar{Y} := Y w,$$

where $w := \frac{1}{E}\mathbb{1} \in \mathbb{R}^E$, and then fit an ordinary least squares model with $\beta \in \mathbb{R}^D$:

$$\beta^* = \arg\min_{\beta} \; (X \beta - \bar{Y})^T (X \beta - \bar{Y})$$

**However, this approach assumes that each of the exam questions matters equally.** I'm wondering if we can relax this assumption to improve generalization by learning feature selection of the targets in the following manner:

Suppose we add constraints like (i) $||w||_1 = 1$ and (ii) $w_e \geq 0$ and instead minimize the following loss function:

$$\beta^*, w^* = \arg \min_{\beta, w} \; (X \beta - Y w)^T (X \beta - Y w) \quad \text{ s.t. } \quad  ||w ||_1 = 1, 0 \leq w_e$$

My questions are:

1. Does this alternative least squares formulation have a solution? If so, what is that solution? Is the solution unique?
2. Assuming a solution exists, what properties will this solution have?
3. Is it possible to show that that this second formulation will have lower test squared error than the first formulation?

Comment: I don't know if that equation has a solution, but the general question you seem to be asking is one of the the central features of item response theory, which has an extensive literature.

Comment: Excellent! Thank you for the terminology. I'll go read up on that! Do you have any recommended references?

Comment: I studied it in grad school, but I got my PhD in 1999, so ... I am WAY out of date. Sorry.

Comment: on point 3, what are you referring to with "first formulation"? the unconstrained one?

Comment: (also, super small note, considering that you have a countable number of $w$, the norm being 1 and $w\ge 0$ already implies that they are lower than 1)

Comment: @AlbertoSinigaglia to your question, I mean the formulation with $w$ uniform.

Comment: To your point, yes, agreed :)

Comment: Sorry but then, given that the 2 formulas disagree only on the set of possible solutions, how can the constrained one have a better solution than the unconstrained one?

Comment: On the training data, agreed. I'm asking about generalization on the test data.